# Problem with closing an created with JS and transition property

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition, createelement

I'm having trouble opening and closing a dynamically created div with Javascript.

The problems are these:

1. In the opening phase, the div created does not follow the transition scale 1s rule
2. When I close the div for the first time it respects the transition and closes correctly, while when I open it a second time the div does not close

Here is the HTML, CSS and JS code:

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stile.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="check">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <label>Ho preso visione dell'<a href="#" class="link">informativa alla privacy</a></label>
        </div>
        
        
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}


#check {
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

label {
line-height: 1.5;
margin-left: 5px;
}

#informativa-privacy {
z-index: 200;
transform: scale(0);
position:fixed;
/* margin-top: 100px; */
top: 0;
left: 0;
/* background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.815); */
height: 100%;
overflow-y: scroll;
transition: all .5s;
}



#informativa-privacy section {
background-color: white;
padding: 10px;
width: 90%;
margin: 20px auto;
}

 #attenzione {   
 font-weight: 800;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 }

#informativa-privacy button {
padding: 10px;
background-color: gold;
box-shadow: 0 0 3px black;
outline: none;
border: none;
display: block;
width: 90%;
margin: 10px auto;
font-weight: 800;
}

#overflow {
height: 200px;
overflow-y: scroll;
margin-bottom: 20px;
border: 1px solid blue;
padding: 5px;

}
```

JS

```
  function apriPrivacy(linkPrivacy) {

   linkPrivacy.onclick = function (e) {

   e.preventDefault()

   let informativa = document.createElement("div")

   informativa.id = "informativa-privacy"

   document.body.appendChild(informativa)

   let contenutoInformativa = `<section>
   <p id="attenzione">LEGGI CON ATTENZIONE</p>

   <div id="overflow">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
   Asperiores inventore voluptatum quidem impedit voluptas vitae 
   ea, amet a autem, quia dicta! Possimus ipsum in earum sapiente 
   architecto odit ad, veniam natus ullam sint esse amet. Fugiat 
   mollitia, unde eos maxime consequuntur officia. Natus rem 
   illum, expedita fugit nam harum, aliquid ducimus ab laboriosam 
   obcaecati, necessitatibus alias repellat numquam tempora! 
   Mollitia molestias ipsa dicta non aut, voluptates placeat. 
   Molestias quibusdam voluptas, tempore deserunt aut cum 
   veritatis ducimus quidem deleniti sapiente nostrum 
   perferendis. Molestias ab tenetur provident tempore ut 
   deserunt nam exercitationem sint labore! Maiores laborum 
   molestias animi repellat eos ratione. Iste, laborum ducimus!   
   Autem nisi quos nobis mollitia voluptate consectetur, placeat 
   minima error earum velit ipsa, numquam blanditiis rerum 
   quibusdam eligendi magni enim itaque fugit modi. Modi dolore 
   quae commodi rem quidem maxime eos architecto delectus alias? 
   Consequatur reprehenderit consequuntur esse tempora architecto 
   minus animi deleniti debitis neque, ut reiciendis nemo.</p>
   </div>

   <button>ACCETTA</button>
        
   </section>`

   informativa.innerHTML = contenutoInformativa

   informativa.style.transition = "transform 1s"

   informativa.style.transform = "scale(1)"

   let bottoneAccetta = document.querySelector("#informativa- 
   privacy button")

   bottoneAccetta.onclick = function () {

   informativa.style.transform = "scale(1)"

   informativa.style.transform = "scale(0)"

   }
    
   }
    
   }
    
   let linkPrivacy = document.querySelector("#check a")
    
   apriPrivacy(linkPrivacy)
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Please format your code correct, so we can easily read it.

Comment: Can you read the code now?

Comment: Yes, I can read it now, thanks. You can also create little codesnippets, it's the button above the question input, that shows `<>`

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is an answer:

Your code didn't work, because everytime someone clicked the link, a new div was created. Then you selected the first "Accetta" button in the document and set it's `onclick` property. For the first time, when only one button is in the whole document, it works, but for all other times, you select the first button in the document, but it is not the one that is visible

I have reordered your code. Now the element (`informativa`) is inserted immediately in the `body` when you call your function `apriPrivacy`.

Then comes the EventListener on the `linkPrivacy` element, in which I add the class `open` to `informativa`. In the CSS I changed the following:

```
#informativa-privacy {
  z-index: 200;
  transform: scale(0);
  position: fixed;
  /* margin-top: 100px; */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.815); */
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  transition: all .5s, transform 1s;
}

#informativa-privacy.open {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

Then in the click EventListener on the `bottoneAccetta` button I remove the class `open` from `informativa` and the CSS is responsible for the animation again.

In the following snippet is your complete code working:

```js
function apriPrivacy(linkPrivacy) {
  let informativa = document.createElement("div");

  informativa.id = "informativa-privacy";

  document.body.appendChild(informativa);

  let contenutoInformativa = `<section>
   <p id="attenzione">LEGGI CON ATTENZIONE</p>
   <div id="overflow">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
   Asperiores inventore voluptatum quidem impedit voluptas vitae 
   ea, amet a autem, quia dicta! Possimus ipsum in earum sapiente 
   architecto odit ad, veniam natus ullam sint esse amet. Fugiat 
   mollitia, unde eos maxime consequuntur officia. Natus rem 
   illum, expedita fugit nam harum, aliquid ducimus ab laboriosam 
   obcaecati, necessitatibus alias repellat numquam tempora! 
   Mollitia molestias ipsa dicta non aut, voluptates placeat. 
   Molestias quibusdam voluptas, tempore deserunt aut cum 
   veritatis ducimus quidem deleniti sapiente nostrum 
   perferendis. Molestias ab tenetur provident tempore ut 
   deserunt nam exercitationem sint labore! Maiores laborum 
   molestias animi repellat eos ratione. Iste, laborum ducimus!   
   Autem nisi quos nobis mollitia voluptate consectetur, placeat 
   minima error earum velit ipsa, numquam blanditiis rerum 
   quibusdam eligendi magni enim itaque fugit modi. Modi dolore 
   quae commodi rem quidem maxime eos architecto delectus alias? 
   Consequatur reprehenderit consequuntur esse tempora architecto 
   minus animi deleniti debitis neque, ut reiciendis nemo.</p>
   </div>
   <button>ACCETTA</button>
   </section>`;

  informativa.innerHTML = contenutoInformativa;

  linkPrivacy.onclick = function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    informativa.classList.add("open");
  }

  let bottoneAccetta = document.querySelector("#informativa-privacy button");

  bottoneAccetta.onclick = function() {
    informativa.classList.remove("open");
  }

}

let linkPrivacy = document.querySelector("#check a");

apriPrivacy(linkPrivacy);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#check {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

label {
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#informativa-privacy {
  z-index: 200;
  transform: scale(0);
  position: fixed;
  /* margin-top: 100px; */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.815); */
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  transition: all .5s, background-color 0s 1s, transform 1s;
}

#informativa-privacy.open {
  background-color: red;
  transform: scale(1);
}

#informativa-privacy section {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

#attenzione {
  font-weight: 800;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#informativa-privacy button {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: gold;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px black;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  font-weight: 800;
}

#overflow {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="check">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>Ho preso visione dell'<a href="#" class="link">informativa alla privacy</a></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Did this help you?

Comment: Yes, I've tried your method now and it works... Only a question if you can answer: I want to add a background-color property when the div have finished the transition. I have to set a timeout for this or can I do it with another method?

Comment: I have changed it in the example code. I changed the transition to `all .5s, background-color 0s 1s, transform 1s`. That tells CSS, that it backgroundcolor should have 0s transition time after 1s.